# how can I add spaces after ." but not after just a " in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I do the following to add spaces after proper end-of-sentence punctuation:

```
string = '"something is wrong."     but then, "why?"  '
new_string = string.squeeze(" ").gsub(/([.?!"]) */,'\1  ')
puts new_string
=> "  something is wrong.  "  but then, "  why?  "
```

My desired result is this:

```
"something is wrong."  but then, "why?"
```

If something is after " to not add spaces unless it's `."` in which case, add the same two spaces I would after a regular  `.`

Answer (score 0):

On the example string you give, I can get the desired result with

```
2.2.0 (main):0 > puts string.squeeze.strip
"something is wrong." but then, "why?"
```

Comment: [String#squeeze](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-squeeze) turns any repeating characters (or specified chars) into a single one.

[String#strip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) removes leading and trailing whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks..so if it makes it just one, why would `"smething is wrong.    "` become `"something is wrong."`?  I asume stripe would only get the white paces characters at the end of the string?

Comment: I get the following:  `irb(main):157:0> puts string.squeeze.strip
=> " something is wrong. " but then, " why? "`  --- there still remains spaces before the "

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. It works as expected on my Mac, Linux & Windows machines running ruby 2.2, 2.1, & 2.0 respectively. I also made a runnable container at http://runnable.com/VM8Z2738jwkd80pu/string-squeeze-strip-demo-for-ruby so you can see it in action.

Comment: Fro the  logic, it seems like it would not remove the space from between `. and `", right?  Squeeze replaces a repeated string with a single space versus removing *all* white space, right?

Comment: In your original string there is no space between `.` and `"`. Your `gsub` is adding it.